# Как выровнять элементы в html?

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять эти элементы не могу понять

Код ниже:

```
.product-list .item {
  width:33%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.product-list .item img {
  width:100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.product-list .item h5 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

[image: Фото]

Comment: Если у вас что-то не получается, оформляйте это сниппетом или в https://jsfiddle.net/ или любой другой песочнице на ваш вкус.

Comment: @DiD jsfiddle как раз запрещён, причём даже на уровне движка сайта

Comment: @andreymal а я и не в курсе, вроде все ссылки на него рабочие, а что с ним не так?

Comment: @DiD зочем нужны ссылки если уже написали 5 ответов 

Answer (score 1):

Использовано: [grid](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D0%B5%CC%88%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-grid-%D0%B2-css-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-220508316f8b), f[lex](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.product__list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, fit-content(25%));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.product__item {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.product__item > * + * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.product__img img {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .product__list {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="product__list">

  <div class="product__item">
    <div class="product__img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    </div>
    <h3 class="product__title">
      Заголовок
    </h3>
    <h3 class="product__title">
      34.99$
    </h3>
  </div>
   <div class="product__item">
    <div class="product__img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    </div>
    <h3 class="product__title">
      Заголовок
    </h3>
    <h3 class="product__title">
      34.99$
    </h3>
  </div>
  
   <div class="product__item">
    <div class="product__img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    </div>
    <h3 class="product__title">
      Заголовок
    </h3>
    <h3 class="product__title">
      34.99$
    </h3>
  </div>
  
  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для `.product-list`(если он родитель) задать такие стили:

```
.product-list {
    /* Ваши стили */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center или flex-start  // center - по центру, flex-start - по верхнему краю
}
```

Про align-items можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/align-items).

Comment: Да, спасибо, я попробую

Comment: Это ничего не поменяло(

Answer (score 0):

Задавая display:flex, используем justify-content:center, чтобы выровнять горзонтально и align-items:center, чтобы вертикально.

Comment: Также не получилось этим способом

Comment: Выровнять надо по какой оси?

Comment: по оси x, чтобы элементы (картинка, название и цена - здесь это один элемент) были ровные, а не как на фото

если нужно доп. код, скажите

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для этого технологию [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
.product-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-list .item {
  width: calc((100% - 10px) / 3); /* Между элементами будет отступ в 5 пикселей */
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-list .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.product-list .item h5 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-list">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="">
    <h5>Item</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="">
    <h5>Item</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="">
    <h5>Item</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```